# Restricting access to the C drive

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there any way I can restrict access to the C drive for one particular group? I've tried setting deny permissions on each folder in the root of the C drive for the group in question, however this doesn't work for folders such as C:\Windows because their permissions cannot be edited even by an administrator.

The [Policy Editor](http://lifehacker.com/5437007/use-the-policy-editor-to-restrict-drive-access-in-windows) approach doesn't help because users are still able to access the C drive if they connect to the server via SFTP (OpenSSH for Windows).

Comment: Have you tried using a Group Policy?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Yeah that's what I'm trying to do. I've created a group and tried to set DENY permissions on each folder in the C drive, however I can't set permissions on folders such as C:\Windows because I get an error similar to this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-s96iRRScuZA/Vqn1mbsTckI/AAAAAAAAA4A/QVLS7paIT1U/s1600/HQgEh.png

Comment: are you logged on as the Admin for your domain?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Yes, I'm logged in as Admin.

Comment: I believe you can edit the permissions on any folder as admin, but you may have to take ownership first.  For example, the `C:\Windows` folder is owned by `TrustedInstaller`.  So, you'd have to change that to `Administrators`, change your security permissions, then change the owner back to `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller`.

Comment: You've tried this, correct? User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer - "Hide these specified drives in My Computer" and "Prevent access to drives from My Computer". Both are set to "Enabled" with the option "Restrict C drive only".

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove That is the policy editor approach I was referring to in my original post. This doesn't help me because users can still navigate through the C drive if they log in via SFTP.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  I think you need to update your question with more details about your **actual problem**.  Are you sure you are really taking the correct approach?    What SFTP daemon are you using?  Is there no way in your sftp daemon to limit the users to a specific folder?  Trying to mess with permissions on the `\Windows` folder is almost certainly the wrong thing to be doing.

Comment: @Zoredache I'm using [OpenSSH for Windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server). There is a "chroot" command that is meant to do exactly what I'm trying to accomplish (i.e. restrict directory access), but it does not work.